# Pandas - Filtering out column based on value

Tags: pandas, filter

I have a Pandas Dataframe that two columns as below (view with header):

```
name,attribute
abc,{'attributes': {'type': 'RecordType', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/RecordType/000xyz'}, 'Name': 'Product 1'}
def,{'attributes': {'type': 'RecordType', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/RecordType/000abc'}, 'Name': 'Product 2'}
klm,{'attributes': {'type': 'RecordType', 'url': '/services/data/v38.0/sobjects/RecordType/000abc'}, 'Name': 'Product 2'}
```

How could I filter out rows that have attribute like 'Product 1'

Could anyone assist, thanks

Comment: What is `print (type(df.loc[0, 'attribute']))` ?

Comment: @jezrael, its <class 'dict'>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension with `get` for working with rows also if not exist key `Name` in some row for boolean mask and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[[x.get('Name') == 'Product 1' for x in df['attribute']]]
```

Or:

```
df = df[df['attribute'].apply(lambda x: x.get('Name')) == 'Product 1']
#alternative, working if all Name exist in each row
#df = df[df['attribute'].apply(lambda x: x['Name']) == 'Product 1']
```

---

```
print (df)
  name                                          attribute
0  abc  {'attributes': {'type': 'RecordType', 'url': '...
```

EDIT:

If want also filter by nested dictionaries:

```
df = df[[x.get('attributes').get('type') == 'RecordType' for x in df['attribute']]]
```

Comment: get an error "KeyError: 'attribute'" when I tried df = df[[x.get('Name') == 'Product 1' for x in df['attribute']]]

Comment: @KevinNash - so it means there is no column `attribute`, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: one more help on this. I need to add a new column and show the value corresponding to Name. How could I modify the above script to store the Name in a new column.

Comment: @KevinNash - use `df['col'] = [x.get('Name') for x in df['attribute']]`

Comment: thanks but just wondering isn't 'Name' a key column. When I try the above get an error KeyError: 'attribute'..

Comment: @KevinNash - `attribute` is column name in dataframe, `Name` is key of dictioanry. So if column name is different, use `df['col'] = [x.get('Name') for x in df['different column name']]` - change `different column name` by your name `print (df.columns.tolist())` show your real data names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183606/discussion-between-kevin-nash-and-jezrael).